# Clang fails to parse C-code when it contains #include for standard header

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm learning to work with clang and I'm currently struggling to make it parsing code where I try to #include standard header file.

Here is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <clang\Basic\DiagnosticOptions.h>
#include <clang\Frontend\TextDiagnosticPrinter.h>
#include <llvm\Support\raw_ostream.h>
#include <clang\Basic\LangOptions.h>
#include <clang\Basic\FileSystemOptions.h>
#include <clang\Basic\FileManager.h>
#include <clang\Basic\SourceManager.h>
#include <clang\Basic\TargetOptions.h>
#include <clang\Basic\TargetInfo.h>
#include <clang\Frontend\CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang\Lex\HeaderSearch.h>
#include <clang\Lex\HeaderSearchOptions.h>
#include <clang\Lex\Preprocessor.h>

int main(void)
{
    clang::DiagnosticOptions diagnosticOptions;
    diagnosticOptions.VerifyDiagnostics = 1;

    clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter *pTextDiagnosticPrinter = new clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter(llvm::outs(), &diagnosticOptions);

    llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticIDs> pDiagIDs(new clang::DiagnosticIDs);

    clang::DiagnosticsEngine *pDiagnosticsEngine = new clang::DiagnosticsEngine(pDiagIDs, &diagnosticOptions);
    pDiagnosticsEngine->setClient(pTextDiagnosticPrinter, true);

    clang::LangOptions languageOptions;

    clang::FileSystemOptions fileSystemOptions;

    clang::FileManager fileManager(fileSystemOptions);

    clang::SourceManager sourceManager(*pDiagnosticsEngine, fileManager);

    std::shared_ptr<clang::TargetOptions> targetOptions = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
    (*targetOptions).Triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();

    clang::TargetInfo *pTargetInfo = clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(*pDiagnosticsEngine, targetOptions);

    clang::CompilerInstance compInst;

    clang::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::HeaderSearchOptions> hsOptions(new clang::HeaderSearchOptions);
    hsOptions.operator*().UseStandardSystemIncludes = 0;
    hsOptions.operator*().UseStandardCXXIncludes = 0;
    hsOptions.operator*().UseBuiltinIncludes = 0;

    hsOptions.operator*().AddPath("c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt", clang::frontend::IncludeDirGroup::Angled, false, false);

    clang::HeaderSearch headerSearch(hsOptions, sourceManager, *pDiagnosticsEngine, languageOptions, pTargetInfo);

    clang::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::PreprocessorOptions> ppOptions;

    clang::Preprocessor preprocessor(ppOptions, *pDiagnosticsEngine, languageOptions, sourceManager, headerSearch, compInst);

    const clang::FileEntry *pFile = fileManager.getFile("test.c");

    clang::FileID mainFileId = sourceManager.createFileID(pFile, clang::SourceLocation(), 
        clang::SrcMgr::CharacteristicKind::C_User);

    sourceManager.setMainFileID(mainFileId);

    preprocessor.EnterMainSourceFile();

    clang::Token token;

    do 
    {
        preprocessor.Lex(token);

        if (pDiagnosticsEngine->hasErrorOccurred())
        {
            break;
        }

        preprocessor.DumpToken(token);

        std::cerr << std::endl;
    } 
    while (token.isNot(clang::tok::eof));
}
```

And here is a code I want to parse:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 4;

extern int j;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error that I get:

> Assertion failed: TextDiag && "Unexpected diagnostic outside source
>   file process ing", file
>   C:\Software\llvm\tools\clang\lib\Frontend\TextDiagnosticPrinter.cpp,
>   line 153

Note, that if I try to include the file which is in the same folder that my source file then it works fine.

I'm using latest version of llvm and clang (3.7.0). I'm working on windows 8.1. Visual studio version is 2015 community edition. I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/wiki/TutorialOrig

Comment: Which OS ? Which command-line ?

Comment: You probably want slash `/` not backslash  \ in `#include` file path

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `\ ` is OK in `#include` file specifications. It's ugly but the Standard has special provisions to support MS/DOS and Windows paths. But I agree with you: `/` are supported by Windows too and would be much more readable, more portable and more elegant.

Comment: @Claudio: I don't use clang executable to compile. I use clang API's to do parsing. My code is executed with no parameters. I just put code to parse in test.c. I run things on windows 8.1.